# PySpark - iterate rows of a Data Frame

Tags: pyspark

I need to iterate rows of a pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame.DataFrame.

I have done it in pandas in the past with the function iterrows() but I need to find something similar for pyspark without using pandas.

If I do `for row in myDF:` it iterates columns.DataFrame

Thanks

Comment: Iteration like `iterrows` is not allowed in pyspark dataframes, Although you use `UDF` to apply function to each row. What do you want to do in iteration?

Comment: I need to access the values of the columns of each row to do comparisons and modifications

Comment: I found a fonctionality called toLocalIterator(). USed as follows: for row in list(alltravelersDF.toLocalIterator()). However takes long time...

Comment: `toLocalIterator()` is used as an alternate to `collect()` and executes jobs one partition at a time. Hence, your driver should have enough memory to accommodate the data of the largest partition in the data. In all, it is better not to use it.

Comment: ok, then what should I use?

Comment: As I mentioned and said in the answer below, you can use `udf` functions untill and unless you dont have dependency between processing of records. For a better answer, you need to explain what exactly you want to do in the function.

Comment: I need to compare each row against value sin another data frame and depending on the result, I need to send the row to another function to make modifications. It is more complex that something that could go into a lambda

Comment: You can join 2 data frames and then try to group, aggregate or window functions to use multiple rows instead of directly iterating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use select method to operate on your dataframe using a user defined function something like this :

```
    columns = header.columns
    my_udf = F.udf(lambda data: "do what ever you want here " , StringType())
    myDF.select(*[my_udf(col(c)) for c in columns])
```

then inside the select you can choose what you want to do with each column .