# How to iterate over rows in a dataframe in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a python script that checks 'i'th row and 'i+1'th row of a column and if they are same, a new column called "Dup" is flagged as "yes" in that particular row else flags as "no". can someone help in converting to pyspark?

```
**i=0
df['Dup']=''
try:
    while(i<=len(df)):
        if (df['column1'][i]==df['column1'][i+1] and df['column2'][i]==df['column2'][i+1]):
            df['Dup'][i]="Yes"
            i=i+1
        else:
            df['Dup'][i]="No"
            i=i+1
except KeyError:
    print ("Row Exception")**
```

The question for me here is. In HDFS, when the input is distributed, how is last row of 1 part of dataframe is used to check the 1st row of 2nd part of the dataframe?

Thanks in advance for your support/clarification.

data you can use this:
ID,Timestamp,group_id,NetgroupID,grouptype,
1,07-07-2019 03:14,513,NULL,1,
2,07-07-2019 03:22,513,NULL,5,
3,17-07-2019 14:56,513,NULL,1,
4,17-07-2019 15:09,513,NULL,5,
5,18-07-2019 09:41,513,NULL,1,
6,18-07-2019 09:50,513,NULL,1,
7,18-07-2019 13:44,513,NULL,5,
8,19-07-2019 08:31,513,NULL,1,
9,20-07-2019 06:24,513,NULL,5,
10,11-09-2019 07:25,514,NULL,1,
11,11-09-2019 07:53,514,NULL,5,
12,11-09-2019 15:20,514,NULL,1,
13,11-09-2019 17:38,514,NULL,5,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PySpark - iterate rows of a Data Frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51152310/pyspark-iterate-rows-of-a-data-frame)

Comment: No.. if i use that solution, i need to return a dataframe but that is not supported in udf.